# adding EventHandler to LinkButtons

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling

There are 2 linkbuttons in page and It seems adding EventHandlers but log doesn't get fired.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var btn in Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").Controls.OfType<LinkButton>())
        {
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(log);
        }
    }

    void log(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
        //somecode
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint to see if `Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").Controls.OfType<LinkButton>()` actually returns anything? The rest looks fine.

Comment: yes It returns 2 items

Comment: Please tag your platform!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is ;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var btn in Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").Controls.OfType<LinkButton>())
        {
            btn.Click += log;
        }
    }

    void log(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
        //somecode
    }
```